# closing goroutine spawned by fiber endpoint

Tags: go, ffmpeg

I have a program that is rtsp cameras to hls format using ffmpeg for streaming.
creating goroutines for each rtsp link as ffmpeg runs in background

Streams are added by following code.

```
func StreamProcess(data <-chan StreamData, ctx context.Context) {
for v := range data {
    ctx, _ := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    go func() {
        if !getStreams(v.camera_id) {
            var stream StreamState
            stream.camera_id = v.camera_id
            stream.state = true
            go Stream(v, ctx)
            wg.Wait()
        } else {
            return
        }
    }()
}
```

}

Streaming function which runs ffmpeg command.

```
func Stream(meta StreamData, ctx context.Context) error {
    log.Println("Started Streaming")
    ffmpegCmd := exec.Command("ffmpeg", "-i", meta.rtsp, "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "-c:v", "libx264", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-b:v", "600k", "-c:a", "aac", "-b:a", "160k", "-f", "rtsp", fmt.Sprintf("rtsp://localhost:8554/%s", meta.camera_id))
    output, _ := ffmpegCmd.CombinedOutput()

    log.Println(string(output))

    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
           log.Println("killing process")
           ffmpegCmd.Process.Kill()
           return nil
        }
    }}
```

my Goal is to stop each os.exec process (ffmpeg command) or at least close all goroutines that are under ffmpeg commands without closing fiber server.

** help required new to golang **

Comment: Why do you use fiber if new to Go? And all your code is unrelated to fiber?

Comment: you are waiting for `CombinedOutput()` (which is ignoring the error, and will cause other problems), so your function never gets to the select block to be canceled. Start the process then check for cancelation, or pass the context to the command to begin with.

Comment: can i get any examples or any reference of what you are saying. it will help a lot.

Comment: You start a command using [`Start`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd.Start), or you could create the command with a context using [`CommandContext`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#CommandContext)

Comment: This worked after after using CommandContext used along with `context.WithCancel(ctx)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working code:

```
func StreamProcess(data <-chan StreamData, ctx context.Context) {
ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
defer cancel()
for {
    select {
    case v, ok := <-data:
        if ok {
            go func() {
                if !getStreams(v.camera_id) {
                    var stream StreamState
                    stream.camera_id = v.camera_id
                    stream.state = true
                    go Stream(v, ctx)
                }
            }()
        } else if !ok {
            cancel()
            return
        }
    case <-ctx.Done():
        log.Println("closed ctx")
        cancel()
    }

}
```

and started streaming with:

```
func Stream(meta StreamData, ctx context.Context) error {
log.Println("Started Streaming")
err := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "ffmpeg", "-i", meta.rtsp, "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "-c:v", "libx264", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-b:v", "600k", "-c:a", "aac", "-b:a", "160k", "-f", "rtsp", fmt.Sprintf("rtsp://localhost:8554/%s", meta.camera_id)).Run()

if err != nil {
    log.Println("error in streaming", err)
    return err
}

log.Println(string("waiting for closure"))
for {
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        log.Println("killing process")          
        return nil
    case <-time.After(2* time.second):
        log.Println("started default context")
        return nil
    }

}
```

.

This works for me now i didn't found any better way. Please comment if anyone is having better way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: again, you are not even getting to the for+select loop because your command blocks. Right now you would run the command, then wait 500 hours after the command is already done. If you want to cancel via the context, and have a timeout, add that timeout to the context.

Comment: yes its true. updated. thanks

Comment: is there any way to stop specific context on user request @JimB. I used to stop os commands with process id in python which is stored in db running command. is there any way to do this in golang?

Comment: Yes, you would call the context cancel function based on the user input.